# Angular, универсальная директива вызова PopUp окон

Tags: angularjs, popup

Изучаю **Angular** и делаю универсальную директиву для вызова PopUp окон.
Что хочу:
В **Dom** должна вызываться через тег

```
<pop-up-dialog url="loginFrame"></pop-up-dialog>
```

где `url="loginFrame"` - идентификатор подгружаемого шаблона.
Что то я запутался уже и не вижу как это реализовать, что бы открытие и закрытие PopUp окон выполнялось с помощью одной директивы.

**script.js**

```js
var mainModule = angular.module("mainModule", [])

var listUrl = [
   {
              name: 'loginFrame', 
              url: '../views/header/loginFrame.html', 
              tag: 'showLoginPopUpDialog', 
              tagvalue: false
            },
   {
              name: 'regFrame', 
              url: '../views/header/regFrame.html', 
              tag: 'showRegPopUpDialog', 
              tagvalue: false
            }
  ];

mainModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
 $scope.onLoginFrame = function(fname) {
  for (var i=0; i < listUrl.length; i++) {
   if( fname == listUrl[i].name) {
    listUrl[i].tagvalue = true;
   }
  }
 }
});

mainModule.directive('popUpDialog', function() {
 return {  //директива подставляет нужные шаблоны, эта часть работает
  restrict: 'E', 
  scope: false, 
  templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
   for (var i=0; i < listUrl.length; i++) {
    if( attrs.url == listUrl[i].name) {
     return listUrl[i].url;
    }
   }
   return '';
  }, 

  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
          // Здесь я хочу добавить в шаблон атрибут ng-show значение которого он будет получать через массив listUrl
   var attrname = 'showLoginPopUpDialog';
   var pudialog = angular.element('<pudialog ng-show="'+attrname+'" pudialog></pudialog>');
   elem.append(pudialog);
  },
 }
});
```

```html
<!-- file loginFrame.html -->
<div class="login-frame-bg" pudialog>
  <h2>Окно авторизации</h2>
  <p>Close</p>
</div>
```

Comment: пока не понятно как это все должно работать, открываться/закрываться, что за директива _pudialog_, которая и как элемент и одновременно как атрибут?

Comment: Я вижу работу так, через url="loginFrame" директива подставляет нужный шаблон и в шаблоне добавляет атрибут ng-show для этого шаблона. Вызов функции ng-click="closePopUpDialog() и ng-click="openPopUpDialog() меняют значение атрибута ng-show.

Comment: что за функции _closePopUpDialog_, _openPopUpDialog_?

Comment: closePopUpDialog, openPopUpDialog их здесь нет потому как я пока не знаю, как будет добавляться атрибут ng-show и что в нем будет. Но если Использовать директиву для одного PopUp окна, то она будут менять значение элемента ng-show="showPopUp" c false на true и наоборот.

Comment: _что за директива pudialog_?

Comment: Это атрибут. Навеяно примером с http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/AgGwK/ для того что бы вставлять ng-show с нужным значением.